# Woocommerce how do I redirect to a Specific Page upon Login?

Tags: authentication, woocommerce

When a user logs in Woocommerce open the MyAccount Page

I need to go to detailing a range of Services we offer.
On that page I want to set a Tick Box if they agree to be called by our Sales staff.

If the users selects this - I would like to set a Session variable which I can use at Cart.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place for free development advice. It's a community to grow and learn with. In the future please make attempts to solve your issue and come with semi-working examples to ask for help.

Comment: Sorry.
I actually found the 3rd one - based on Role 
but didn't work for me.
Also didn't know how to set a session variable which I can use at cart.
I need to Click on a Link, Set a Session variable and goto Shop page 
So I thought I'd ask a question on how to do it - may be the Role based code was not appropriate.

Always learning..

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets that will guide you to do that

After login:-

```
// Custom redirect for users after logging in
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wcs_login_redirect');
function wcs_login_redirect( $redirect ) {
     $redirect = 'http://google.com/';
     return $redirect;
}
```

After login but just after register:-

```
// Custom redirect for users after logging in

    add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wcs_register_redirect');
    function wcs_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
         $redirect = 'http://google.com/';
         return $redirect;
    }
```

Redirect the user based on their role :-

```
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    $dashboard = admin_url();
    $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    if( $role == 'administrator' ) {
        //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {
        //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'editor' ) {
        //Redirect editors to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'author' ) {
        //Redirect authors to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {
        //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
        $redirect = $myaccount;
    } else {
        //Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
        $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I actually found the 3rd one - based on Role 
but didn't work for me.
Also didn't know how to set a session variable which I can use at cart.
I need to Click on a Link, Set a Session variable and goto Shop page 
So I thought I'd ask a question on how to do it - may be the Role based code was not appropriate.

Comment: each of the code snippets are well tested , you may need some customization .